# How do you create/display a twitter-like feed in TriggerIO

Tags: trigger.io

I am trying to create a mobile app with one of the functions being a twitter-like feed. The twitter feed will display messages coming from the server. What would be the best way to implement this using TriggerIO?

Answer (score 1):

One way that is almost identical to a desktop web application:

1. Utilize the Twitter API to pull down Json.
2. Update your DOM.
3. Utilize setInterval() to check for updates every X amount of minutes.
4. Update your DOM with new status updates.

Here is a great Twitter trigger.io tutorial to get you started:

http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/03/02/how-to-build-fast-html5-mobile-apps-using-backbone-js-zepto-js-and-trigger-io/